# Scala: how to get random element form given list

Tags: scala, random

I want to pick random element from given list:

```
  def randomAlphaNumericChar(): Char = {
    val ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789".toCharArray
    Gen.oneOf(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING)
  }
```

So currently this now compile:

> type mismatch;  found   : org.scalacheck.Gen[Char]  required: Char
>       Gen.oneOf(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING)

Comment: The exception is really clear. You expect the function to return `Char` while the method you're using returns `Gen[Char]`. Fix one of the above.

Comment: @AvihooMamka Nitpick - It's not an *exception*, it's a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

```
  def randomAlphaNumericChar(): Char = {
  /*
     ASCII Codes
     [0-9]: (48 to 57)
     [A-Z]: (65 to 90)
     [a-z]: (97 to 122)
  */
    val alphabet = (48 to 57) union (65 to 90) union (97 to 122)
    val i = scala.util.Random.nextInt(alphabet.size)
    alphabet(i).toChar
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
val xs = ('a' to 'z') ++ ('A' to 'Z') ++ (1 to 9)
```

try

```
xs.maxBy(_ => scala.util.Random.nextInt)
```

Here `maxBy` applies a function to each element of the collection and then selects the maximum value returned by the function applied to each element. In this case the function is a random value returned from `Random.nextInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
def randomAlphaNumericChar(): Char = {
    val ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789".toList
    scala.util.Random.shuffle(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING).head
}
```